# jQuery Moble go back one page if possible, otherwise go here

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

In jQuery mobile is it possible to check if history.back() would be a page in the application?  If it isn't a page in the application, then I want to direct to a specific page.

Example:
User clicks login from the home page and goes to login.html.  The login is handled successfully and history.back() is called and the user goes back to the home page.

User enters at login.html.  The login is handled successfully and since the user did not come from another page in the app, they are taken to account.html.

Comment: Probably want to determine this on your server. On your server, check for the URL referrer. If it's something from the app, put a Javascript boolean on the page as `true`, otherwise `false`. Then use this boolean for your determination in Javascript

Comment: common way of doing this is to pass the `return to` URL (often in the querystring) to the login page, e.g. `login.html?redirect=/home.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by storing the redirect page.